# Matlab Structures: How to compare the contents of structure? Getting the following error

Tags: matlab, structure

I have the structure below with the value. When I try to compare the value of the field I get the error below. What can I do?

Input

```
XYZ.Element_2 =='Fundamental'
if XYZ.Element_2 == 'RMS'
    var33=1
else
    var33=0
end
```

Output

```
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in sample50main (line 38)
if XYZ.Element_2 == 'RMS'
```

Comment: Use [`strcmp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) to compare character arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue is that MATLAB is trying to do a character array comparison and since those arrays do not have an equal number of characters a dimension error is thrown. An implementation that could resolve this may be by doing a string comparison using double quotes `""`. Alternatively, you can use the `strcmp()` function as described in the comment above. Below are both implementations:

### Method 1: Using Double Quotes

**Condition True:**

```
XYZ.Element_2 = 'Fundamental';

if XYZ.Element_2 == "RMS"
    var33 = 1;
else
    var33 = 0;
end
```

**Condition False:**

```
XYZ.Element_2 = 'RMS';

if XYZ.Element_2 == "RMS"
    var33 = 1;
else
    var33 = 0;
end
```

### Method 2: Using `strcmp()` Function

**Condition True:**

```
XYZ.Element_2 = 'Fundamental';

if strcmp(XYZ.Element_2,'RMS')
    var33 = 1;
else
    var33 = 0;
end
```

**Condition Flase:**

```
XYZ.Element_2 = 'RMS';

if strcmp(XYZ.Element_2,'RMS')
    var33 = 1;
else
    var33 = 0;
end
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**